# VBA Code is throwing Error Number 1004

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

**Using MS Office 2010**

This is my first macro code.
It's very much like a Vlookup, the difference is that in the Source Array, there is not an exact match but a range.

```
Size1 >= CSng(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(StartNumber, 2)) And Size1 <= CSng(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(StartNumber, 3)))
```

If lookup value comes in that Range and other parameters also match then that's a desired value.

But when I'm trying to run this code there's **Error number 1004** in *Function EIL_Code* for every row.

I tried converting all data to a specfic type such as String, Single etc.

Copied the whole data and removed all formatting from it but still, it's not working.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    On Error GoTo MyErrorHandler:

'    Table1 = Sheet1.Range("A1:S4386")
'    Table2 = Sheet2.Range("A1:L1927")

    EndNumber = 4386

    For StartNumber = 2 To EndNumber
        Spec_Item = CStr(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(StartNumber, 1))
        Size1_LT = CSng(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(StartNumber, 2))
        Size2_LT = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(StartNumber, 3)

        Sheet1.Cells(StartNumber, 4) = EIL_Code(Spec_Item, Size1_LT)

    Next StartNumber


MyErrorHandler:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        MsgBox "Employee Not in the table."

    ElseIf Err.Number = 13 Then
        MsgBox "Employee Not Present in the table."

    End If


End Sub
```

---

```
Function EIL_Code(ByVal Spec_Item As String, ByVal Size1 As Single) As String

    On Error GoTo MyErrorHandler:

    EndNumber1 = 1927

    For StartNumber1 = 2 To EndNumber1

        If (Spec_Item = CStr(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(StartNumber, 1))) And (Size1 >= CSng(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(StartNumber, 2)) And Size1 <= CSng(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(StartNumber, 3))) Then
            EIL_Code = CStr(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(StartNumber, 4))
        End If

    Next StartNumber1

MyErrorHandler:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        MsgBox "Error Number 1004."

    ElseIf Err.Number = 13 Then
        MsgBox "Error Number 13."
    End If


End Function
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you got `.Cells(StartNumber, 1)` in your code but your for loop is using `StartNumber1` instead of `StartNumber`. I recommend to declare all variables and use `Option Explicit` to avoid such situations. See [VBA Best Practices - Always use 'Option Explicit'](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices).

Comment: @Peh: It worked.Thanks a lot for pointing out the error.
And also thanks for your suggestion of using "Option Explicit", will do it from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code offers many possibilities for errors to occur. I re-wrote it so as to make it readable.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(StartNumber)
    ' Debug.Print CStr(.Cells(1).Value) 
    ' Debug.Print CSng(.Cells(2).Value)
    ' Debug.Print CSng(.Cells(3).Value)
    If (Spec_Item = CStr(.Cells(1).Value)) And _
                   (Size1 >= CSng(.Cells(2).Value)) And _
                   (Size1 <= CSng(.Cells(3).Value)) Then
        EIL_Code = CStr(.Cells(4).Value)
    End If
End With
```

Most importantly, perhaps, you should use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code sheet, so that VBA can point out naming errors to you. Secondly, don't confuse VBA or yourself or both by not declaring whether you are talking about a cell or its value. Always add `.Value` to a range's (or cell's) definition if you mean to refer to its value.

An error would also result if `.Cells(2).Value)` in `CSng(.Cells(2).Value))` doesn't hold an expression that can be converted to a Single data type.

Finally, I have added three lines of code to print each of the expressions you test to the Immediate Window. You can use such features to find out which of the three is giving the problem.